# function to write initials using x's

Tags: python

I have been tasked to write a function that will print within itself my initials. if you have no initials it prints x in the middle, I don't have a middle initial. He told us to go ahead and hard code the list we were going to input into the function.

So my function grabs a list with the column number where x should be printed. It goes through the numbers in the list, checks if it equals the index number and if it does it prints a x, if it doesn't not it prints white space, then it decreases the index value by 1, and repeats the process until all numbers in the list have been checked. I'm supposed to do all so that the function goes through each line (1st list) of the 2nd list but I cant get it to do that so I just replicated the 2nd list in 1st and ran the function with all the 1st list. this is my code

```
import sys
# function thst takes each row of the namelist and determines where to print x
def oned (row) :

        index = 11            
        while index >= 0 :
            for numbers in row :
                if numbers == index :
                    sys.stdout.write('X')
                else :
                    sys.stdout.write(' ')
                index = index - 1
        print


#Main

namelist = [[11, 2, 1, 0],
            [11, 2],
            [11, 2],
            [11, 8, 5, 2, 1, 0],
            [11, 7, 6, 0],
            [11, 7, 6, 0],
            [11, 8, 5, 2, 1, 0]]

testrow0 = [11, 2, 1, 0]
testrow1 = [11, 2]
testrow2 = [11, 2]
testrow3 = [11, 8, 5, 2, 1, 0] #only prints 11, 2, 1, 0 needs 8, 5
testrow4 = [11, 7, 6, 0]       #only prints 11, 0 needs 7,6
testrow5 = [11, 7, 6, 0]       #skips over 7, 6 like other one
testrow6 = [11, 8, 5, 2, 1, 0] #skips over 8, 5 

oned (testrow0)
oned (testrow1)
oned (testrow2)
oned (testrow3)
oned (testrow4)
oned (testrow5)
oned (testrow6)
```

out put is

```
X        XXX
X        X  
X        X  
X        XXX
X          X
X          X
X        XXX
```

Which is what I want but the x in between is missing. I can't seem to find the error that is causing this so if you can find it please let me know.

I want the output to look like:

```
X        XXX
X        X  
X        X  
X  X  X  XXX
X   XX     X
X   XX     X
X  X  X  XXX
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not had a chance to test this, but I believe the `index=index-1` is misplaced.  When you change `index`, you are saying that you are done with this column and are going on to the next column.  That should happen either when you have just printed an x, or after you have checked the whole row.  The code now decrements `index` at the same time it is walking through `row`.

**edit**
Three changes make this cleaner and correct (tested on Python 2.7.3).

1. You don't need to iterate over the row to see whether `index` is in the row.  The `in` operator will do that for you!
2. The `while` loop always steps 11, 10, ..., 0.  Since the bounds never change, and the increment is always -1, it's a good candidate for a `for` loop instead.  The `range(11,-1,-1)` makes `[11, 10, ..., 0]`.  `11` is the start, the first `-1` is the number *after* the last number you want, and the second `-1` is the increment (decrease each time rather than increasing).
3. And I renamed `index` to be more descriptive.

   ```
   def oned (row):
       for colindex in range(11,-1,-1):   # replaces the while loop
           if colindex in row:            # replaces the for loop
               sys.stdout.write('X')
           else:
               sys.stdout.write(' ')
       print
   ```

Comment: i tried it and it just jacked up the whole code, although what you say makes sence